# Passing array to a function in C to store data

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, null

I’m new to C and here I'm trying to read integers (separated by whitespaces) from a file and store them in an array called `array`.

Initially, I set `array` to `NULL` and then pass it to the `read_file` function. Everything works fine within `read_file`. However, when `read_file` is popped off the stack, `array` still points to `NULL` and not to the data loaded by `read_file`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int read_file(FILE *file, int *input_array);

FILE *file;

int main(){
    char *pathname = " numbers.txt";
    if(fopen_s(&file, pathname, "r"))
        puts("File could not be opened.");

    int *array = NULL;
    int array_size = read_file(file, array);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}

int read_file(FILE *file, int *input_array){
    int array_size = 10;
    input_array = (int *) malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; !feof(file) && i < array_size; i++){
        fscanf_s(file, "%d", &input_array[i]);
        //printf("%d\n", input_array[i]);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: down vote simply because you should have learned this in college, or some moment far before you start writing code.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `input_array` is passed *by value* to the function. So the actual argument `array` does not change it's value. In order to alter the value of `array` you will need to pass a reference (pointer) to it in a way similar to:

```
int read_file(FILE *file, int **input_array){ ...
```

And then change the access to it accordingly inside the function.

But a better idea might be to pass a pre-allocated array to the function, such that the function will only alter its *content*, so the signature will remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

`input_array` is local to `read_file`, so the fact that you assign it a value is lost when the function returns. If you want to assign a value to the variable `array`, then you'll have to pass a pointer to that into the function.  I.e.:

```
array_size = read_file(file, &array);

. . .

int read_file(FILE *file, int **input_array) {
    . . .
    *input_array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));
```